# Why GitHub page not deploy feature control layout when I use leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, github, leaflet, github-pages

I have a program use leaflet to create simple web like google map, and I have a feature is change between maps like: Google Street, Google Satellite, Dark Map,...

But it's not working.

So this is my file structure:

[image]

And I have a piece of code is control layouts in Leaflet:

```
var baseMaps = {
        OSM: osm,
        "Water color map": watercolor,
        Dark: dark,
        "Google Street": googleStreets,
        "Google Satellite": googleSat,
      };
      var overlayMaps = {
        "Point Data": pointData,
        "Line Data": lineData,
        "Polygon Data": polygonData,
      };
      // map.removeLayer(singleMarker)

      L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
```

This is my link sources code: https://github.com/nvhai248/Leaflet_Basic
This is my GitHub Page web deploy this project: https://nvhai248.github.io/Leaflet_Basic/

Thank you for reading my problem!

Comment: "It's not working". Please share what the error actually is